# If three dice are rolled, what is the probability that the number appear will be greater than the previous roll

Tags: probability

The dice is fair.

My procedure is to make cases. ex probability of each number on first roll is 2/3 (as if 5 ,6 comes we can't have desired outcome). Now if 1 comes then then probability of 2,3,4,5,is 2/3.Now multiply these two probability and make 4 more cases for the next roll.Now similarly do for 2,3,4 on the first roll

I can solve the question but my procedure requires a lot of time and effort.Is there a better way of solving the question

Comment: So to clarify, you want the rolls of the die to be in strictly increasing order?

Comment: ok ,I thought stricty increasing means (1,2,3)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Even more simply: there are $6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ sequences with all three throws different; of these, one in six will be strictly increasing.

Comment: @TonyK Absolutely. And more directly $6\choose 3$, since counting increasing sequences is exactly equivalent to counting unordered sequences - which generalizes to $k$ "dice" with $n$ "faces" each.

Answer (score 3):

To satisfy the required condition all three rolls should be different. Thus there are altogether $\binom 63$ "winning" combinations and the probability in question is $$\frac1{6^3}\binom 63.$$